# zf2 routing issue with segments

Tags: zend-framework2

I try to route with multiple segments like the below

htpro/doc/appointments/15/10/2014

```
'doc' => array(

                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/doc[/:action][/:app_day][/:app_month][/:app_year]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'doc\Controller\Doc',
                        'action'     => 'appointments',
                    ),
                ),

            ),
```

but i am getting the follwoing error, what might be the issue

The requested URL could not be matched by routing.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
'doc' => array(

            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/htpro/doc[/:action][/:app_day][/:app_month][/:app_year]', //add /htpro
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'app_day' => '[0-9]*',   // add this 
                    'app_month' => '[0-9]*', // add this 
                    'app_year' => '[0-9]*',  // add this 
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'doc\Controller\Doc',
                    'action'     => 'appointments',
                ),
            ),

        ),
```

but you still need to define your costum constraints.

Comment: but still the same issue